# Generating all possible combinations in a nested dictionary

Tags: python, testing, python-itertools

I need to test all possible installation configurations possible. The configurations are kept in a dictionary array that sometimes contains nested arrays.

Here's a sample of the configuration information (actual configuration is much longer):

```
config = {'database': 'sqlite',
          'useExisting': False,
          'userCredentials': {'authType': 'windows', 
                              'user': r'.\Testing', 
                              'password': 'testing'
                             }
         }
```

For `database`, options are `['sqlite','mysql','oracle']`, and for `useExisting`, the options are `[True, False]`. I can figure out how to go through all permutations of those.

But for `userCredentials`, the options can be quite different. If `authType` is `database`, I need additional parameters. I can create a function that'll loop through and create all valid combinations, but how do I join them? Or is there a better way to generate the configurations?

The `userCredentials` may also have different settings. For instance, I have two user accounts, testing1 and testing2. I'll need to run the tests with both user accounts, and preferably with all possible configurations. I'm having trouble figuring out how to recursively generate all configurations when it's nested like this.

Comment: I'm not sure, but check out Itertools, maybe you'll find something. http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html

Comment: @TankorSmash, I've looked into itertools. With it, I'm able to generate all possible combinations if I don't have anything nested, but I don't see a way to use it to generate the dictionaries I need directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?  It builds all combinations of database, useExisting, and authType listed using [intertools.product](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).  If authType is 'database' it updates the userCredentials with additional parameters.  Modify as needed:

```
from itertools import product

def build_config(db,flag,authType,userPass):
    config = dict(database=db,useExisting=flag)
    config['userCredentials'] = {
        'authType': authType, 
        'user': userPass[0], 
        'password': userPass[1]
    }
    if authType == 'database':
        config['userCredentials'].update(
            dict(extra=1,param=2))
    return config

database = ['sqlite','mysql','oracle']
useExisting = [True, False]
authType = ['windows','database']
userPass = [('testing1','pass1'),('testing2','pass2')]

for options in product(database,useExisting,authType,userPass):
    config = build_config(*options)
    print config
```

Comment: This seems to work well! One thing I realised I didn't explain well in my original question (and I'll edit it to update); I also need to have different permutations of items inside `config`. For example, `userCredentials` may use a `testing1` user and a `testing2` user. I'd imagine I can just use `itertools.product` again, but I'm struggling to figure out how that works recursively with `itertools`.

Comment: Updated with user/password permutations.  Note how it keeps the correct password with the correct user.  You wouldn't want to permute over users AND passwords.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, and much cleaner code then I was coming up with. Thank you, Mark!