# Extracting All Combinations in nested dictionary python

Tags: python, dictionary, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dictionary like:

```
{'6400': {'6401': '1.0', '6407': '0.3333333333333333', '6536': '0.0', '6448': '0.0'}}
```

And I would like to product a structure similar to preferably in Pyspark:

```
('6400',['6400','6401','1.0'])
('6400',['6400','6407','0.3333333333333333'])
('6400',['6400','6536','0.0'])
('6400',['6400','6448','0.0'])
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generating all possible combinations in a nested dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12178291/generating-all-possible-combinations-in-a-nested-dictionary)

Comment: @Jeremy No pyspark tag though.

Comment: sorry corrected typo.

Comment: Can you solve it in Python and try to adapt it to PySpark?

Comment: Might consider using dict.items(), itertools.repeat(), and zip().

Answer (score 2):

If you do this in python you can use following code to produce the structure you want.

```
d = {'6400': {'6401': '1.0', '6407': '0.3333333333333333', '6536': 
'0.0', '6448': '0.0'}}
result = []
for outer_e in d:
    for inner_e in d[outer_e]:
        e = [outer_e, inner_e, d[outer_e][inner_e]]
        e = (outer_e, e)
        result.append(e)
```

Answer (score 1):

Little bit bulky, but another way to solve problem:

```
In [1]: d = {'6400': {'6401': '1.0', '6407': '0.3333333333333333', '6536': '0.0'
   ...: , '6448': '0.0'}}

In [2]: map(lambda item: [(item[0], [item[0], *i]) for i in item[1].items()], d.items())
Out[2]: <map at 0x104563e48>

In [3]: list(_)
Out[3]:
[[('6400', ['6400', '6401', '1.0']),
  ('6400', ['6400', '6407', '0.3333333333333333']),
  ('6400', ['6400', '6536', '0.0']),
  ('6400', ['6400', '6448', '0.0'])]]
```

And since it unordered `dict` object, you can't rely on order.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help it worked. !!